# Cambiar imagen de fondo de un TitledPane

Tags: javafx

Mediante un listener pretendo cambiar la imagen de fondo de un `TitledPane` aunque no lo he logrado. Al iniciar el código, la hoja de estilo muestra la 'flechaAbajo.png' pero al expandir/contraer el `TitledPane` desaparece la imagen y no se muestra nada. Las imágenes que utilizo están en la misma carpeta que el código y que la hoja de estilos. El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
    titledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((obs, contraído, expandido) -> {
            if (expandido) {        
                titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle(
                     "-fx-background-image : url('flechaAbajo.png'); "    
                );
            } else {
                titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle(
                    "-fx-background-image : url('flechaArriba.png'); " 
                );                
            }
        });
```

La hoja de estilo es:

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-image : url('flechaAbajo.png'); 
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con CSS:

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-position: right;
}
.titled-pane:expanded > .title {
    -fx-background-image : url('flechaAbajo.png'); 
}
.titled-pane:collapsed > .title {
    -fx-background-image : url('flechaArriba.png'); 
}
```